# Angular Guage Chart in R

Tags: javascript, angularjs, r, highcharts

Assuming I have simple test data

```
   Col1        Value
   Weight      120
```

I am curious how to plot an Angular JChart in R using this test dataset.

Although through JFiddle one can see the underlining [Java Script code](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-speedometer/) or JFiddle code. I am not sure how to integrate this JFiddle Angular JChart code into R.

In a sense it looks simple because it seems as though one would just change the value in this portion of the code from 80 to 120, but how would anybody assign a value to this parameter from R dataframe and interweave this code in R framework is something I am not familiar with.

```
series: [{
            name: 'Speed',
            data: [80],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' km/h'
            }
        }]
```

Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: Could you explain what is this JChart you mentioned? For using Highcharts with AngularJS you could see this [official Highcharts article](http://www.highcharts.com/blog/194-using-highcharts-with-angular-js).

Comment: @KacperMadej, Thanks Kacper